# Requirements for stand alone Bot with skill template

Tags: botframework

We have developed chat bot using skill template and integrated with a parent bot, But now our requirement has been changed so we have to integrate as stand alone.

Que. Can we proceed with current skill template or we need any additional feature to be integrate for stand alone bot.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: How long ago was the skill created via the skill template? How extensive is the skill? I ask because skills have changed considerably recently and it may be easiest to start the bot from scratch. That being said, a skill is mostly just a bot, anyway. Basically just reverse [these docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/skill-implement-skill?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=cs) and remove anything it tells you to add.